# The text displayed on my HTML button is including more than it should

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

[Here is a reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miu77.png)

For a little bit more context I am operating in a C# ASP.NET MVC environment and I am trying to pass a value to a form via button click. For my other two values that are being assigned on the form I am using @Html.EditorFor() and @Html.RadioButtonFor() for a text box and radio button selection respectively. However since there is no @Html.ButtonFor() I am instead trying to assign the value to the form with @Html.HiddenFor() inside of an onclick. This works in terms of the functionality I want from it, but there is a weird visual issue where the symbols following the onclick are also used in the text displayed on the button, so while the button should display the text:

- Save Notification

It actually displays

- "> Save Notification

Here is the relevant code (with specifically the button markup at the bottom where the issue is taking place). I feel like I am missing something very obvious here and I am very new to HTML and Kendo so I am really lost as to why this is happening.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 ref-bottom-margin">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SystemStatus.UniversalNotification.SystemNotification, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SystemStatus.UniversalNotification.BannerSeverity, "Alert")
            Alert &nbsp; &nbsp;
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SystemStatus.UniversalNotification.BannerSeverity, "Warning")
            Warning &nbsp; &nbsp;
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SystemStatus.UniversalNotification.BannerSeverity, "Notification")
            Notification &nbsp; &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Universal" onclick="@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SystemStatus.UniversalNotification.BannerScope)"> Save Notification </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What if you remove `onclick="@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Syst....` ?

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.HiddenFor` will generate `"` inside onclick attribute, and causing wrong text display

Rendered source code of the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Universal" onclick="<input id="SystemStatus_UniversalNotification_BannerScope" name="SystemStatus.UniversalNotification.BannerScope" type="hidden" value="" />"> Save Notification </button>
```

Instead of using `@Html.HiddenFor`, you can get the value from model using `@(Model.fieldname)`. And maybe you will want to pass the value directly into JavaScript function, like below

```
onclick="someFunction('@(Model.SystemStatus.UniversalNotification.BannerScope)')"
```